# How escape pipe charachter in MediaWiki parser function?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

How do I escape a pipe character using a MediaWiki parser function?

Replacing a backslash by a hyphen can be like this:

```
{{#vardefine:varName|test\test\test}}
{{#vardefine:varName2|{{#replace:{{#var:varName}}|\|-}}}}
{{#var:varName2}}
```

But replacing a pipe character ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in magic word `{{!}}` instead of litteral pipes.

Comment: Thanks a lot IRA1777.