# How do you pass a pipe in a template parameter

Tags: mediawiki

How can I pass a pipe in a template parameter. I want to pass a small table in the text

Say something like this. I tried converting `|` to `{{!}}` but that didnt work

```
{{FormatSomeText
|text=This is before the table
{|
! My Table !! And more
|}
This is after
}}
```

And the template would use the above something like

```
== Begin ==
{{{text|}}}
== End ==
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How escape pipe charachter in MediaWiki parser function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773762/how-escape-pipe-charachter-in-mediawiki-parser-function)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your MediaWiki version is too old, the following should work:

```
{{FormatSomeText
|text=This is before the table
{{{!}}
! My Table !! And more
{{!}}}
This is after
}}
```

If your MW version is below 1.24, define `Template:!`, containing `<includeonly>|</includeonly>`.

Comment: I tried the `{{!}}` replacement before posting, it didn't work. I wonder if it was some caching, I'll try it again

Answer (score 2):

Another way to represent a pipe character in wikitext is to use an HTML entity reference: `&#124;`

Answer (score 1):

{{!}} should do the job as @Alexander mentioned